# Position absolute dropdown over position sticky column

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, sticky

Is there a way to have an absolutely positioned dropdown scroll on top of a position stickied column with css?[image: dropdown scroll]

The desired effect is to have the `savings` column scroll behind still but have `my dropdown` on top of column `month`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/devcon/pen/xxwxZZp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood the intention correctly:

You could add `z-index: 1;` to `table th`, and increase z-index for `th:first-child` (e.g. `z-index: 2;`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does indeed [seem to work for me](https://codepen.io/devcon/pen/RwWPgBV). Bless you.

Comment: i'm glad it does!